# How do I display output from php msqli page with the same website?

Tags: php, html, wamp

I am working on html page. It has a button and a text box `<input type="text"></input> , <button onclick="abcdef">Search</button>`. The button will make an overlay page "visible" which contents is normally hidden from view which also has close buttons to close it again. Basically, everything happens "on the same page". I used a java script to hide and show that overlay.

I made a php page (search.php) , that will search a database for a string value. I used a form with another `<input type="text"></input>` and `<input type="submit" name="search"></input>` for this with form using `method="GET"` and `action="search.php"`. I do get to use this and input a value into the input text box. And when I click on search it will open a NEW PAGE and display either "nothing found" or the result intended.

I would like to use my first button and the input box. I would also like this output to be displayed in my overlay page that is made "visible" by that button. The whole form thing messes up my overlay or opens on a new page. If possible I would like to display all the output from the php page on the same , root, index html page INSIDE my overlay.

**How do I code the search.php and my index.html page in such as way as to display the output inside my overlay when I click the button ?** Currently, the search.php along with the above-mentioned form will output as in `echo "<h1>", $result['name'],"</h1><h2>",$result['surname'],"</h2>;` on a new page by using a while loop to display all the results.

*Idea: When I click on the button ( called Search), it should take the value from the input box, send it to the php script and perform the search and return results, then open the overlay and display the results in the overlay. Or when the button is clicked, it should first load into the overlay, then get the text from the input box, then do the search and then display the search results in the overlay.*

Comment: Just Google it.. What have you tried so far..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your `search.php` to return only `JSON` string, and making an `AJAX` call using javascript fetch the `JSON` response from the `search.php` and render the data using JavaScript.

You can use `JQuery` or `AngularJS`. Both will do the needful for you.

Or else, change your `index.html` to `index.php` and `action="index.php"` and integrate your functionality of `search.php` to `index.php`.

This is the best thing you can do. The problem is not displaying the data, it is about fetching the data properly. Better use the 1st method, lot of learning is required but will do it neatly.

Comment: The second option sounds perfect ! Unfortunately I cannot test this at the moment, but I will as soon as I am on the server again. Many thanks in advance  !

Comment: Then go ahead and convert your index.html to index.php and add the search functionality there.

Comment: Many thanks again @Veer Shrivasta : I tested this with the php code inside the page and renamed to php and it works !